# <?php wp_head(); ?> needs to be right before </head>?

Tags: php, wordpress

According to the [Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head), the wp_head(); should be located right before the closing head tag.

When I insert the code after the wp_head(); it works. But when I insert it before wp_head(); as it should be, it results in a blank space. Look at the picture to see what Firebug sais when it goes blank.

This is the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider/flexslider.css" type="text/css" /> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">   $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({

         slideshow: true,
         controlNav: false,
         directionNav: false,   animation: "slide",     slideshowSpeed: 4500,   animationDuration: 600,   

             });   }); </script>
```

Firebug: [image]

How come is that? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js` has loaded? You should probably use an absolute URL.

Comment: I don't see either in the code you posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `wp_head()` should be before `</head>`, but your javascript code should be before `</body>`.

Javascript is always recommended to be put in the end of the DOM. In case that is not possible (e.g. specific javascript must be loaded before the DOM, which does not seem to be true in your case) , put it before `</head>` and after `wp_head();`

**EDIT**

Also, what I noticed in your case is that your main script might not be accessible if you are using SEO friendly urls. You should specify absolute url.

Comment: Do you mean that I should put the java script in the body and just keep the css link and the two script links in the header? This is where I got the code from: http://flex.madebymufffin.com/ They say it all should be in the header.

Comment: They are wrong, javascript should always be at the end of the dom (just before </body>) (except in very specific cases). So yes, you need to put css in the head and move that javascript code to the end of the body.

Comment: Maybe it is okay to put it between wp_head and </head>  anyway?

Comment: it is okay, but it is better to have it before `</body>` if it works that way.

Comment: The problem you are experiencing is that plugin & jquery itself is loaded via `wp_head()` call, so you can't insert custom plugin code before `wp_head()` because plugin itself will not be actually loaded yet.

Comment: I will try before </body>. I should leave the script import in the header? Only move the javascript?

Comment: I recommend moving flex script to the </body> as well. I also updated my answer.